# Centreon - fail to add host

Tags: nagios

I just installed the version 2.5.2 of Centreon, but I'm getting a weird behavior.

When I try to add a host, through Configuration --> Hosts --> Add, fill all the required fields, and Save, it simply does not include the host, and doesn't throw any error message in the front-end.

I have also checked the following log files and have not found any error, not even a clue on what is happening.

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log /var/log/messages /usr/local/centreon/log/centAcl.log
/usr/local/centreon/log/dashboardBuilder.log
/usr/local/centreon/log/login.log /usr/local/centreon/log/centcore.log /usr/local/centreon/log/downtimeManager.log
/usr/local/centreon/log/nagiosPerfTrace.log /usr/local/centreon/log/centreon-purge.log
/usr/local/centreon/log/eventReportBuilder.log /usr/local/centreon/log/sql-error.log /usr/local/centreon/log/centstorage.log /usr/local/centreon/log/logAnalyser.log
```

I wonder if anyone has experienced this problem and could help me.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using PHP version 5.4 or above? If so, Centreon needs a PHP version earlier than 5.3. it's a compatibility issue. Note the caveat for 5.3.2...

http://www.centreon.com/Content-Products-IT-network-monitoring/supported-software-and-requirements

Comment: yes, that it is. I´ve downgraded the php to 5.3.3, and the centos from 7 to 6, now it is working fine...thank you very much!